# Overload not considered even though it looks like a better match

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

This is rejected by both [gcc (live on godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/Q_22RC) and clang:

```
#include <string>

namespace
{
    std::string
    to_string(char const (&str) [14])
    { return str; }
}

void f()
{
    using std::to_string;
    char const hello[14] = "Hello, World!";
    (void) to_string(hello);
}
```

The compiler considers each of the [`std::to_string` overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and conclude with:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'to_string(const char [14])'
> ```

If I remove `using std::to_string`, my overload is considered and called. Why? How to fix it (other than removing the *using*)?

Comment: Add another using, `using ::to_string;`

Comment: Why can't you remove `using std::to_string;`? It seems like a reasonable thing to do so functions with the same name but from different namespaces won't mix.

Comment: @VTT Think templates ;) IRL `f` is a template function `<class T>` and `hello` has type `T const&`. `using std::to_string` allows `f` to work for `T`= any type from `std::to_string` overloads + my owns.

Comment: It seems like you don't consider name `to_string` potentially referring to unrelated functions in different namespaces to be a problem.

Comment: @VTT Yes, I don't consider it to be a problem. More specifically, if I have a function called `to_string` in my program that doesn't take an argument and return its representation as a `std::string`, I've got other priorities to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of the using declaration matters. It's a proper declaration, so name hiding takes effect. Inside the function the global scope version isn't visible. You need to reintroduce it:

```
using ::to_string;
using std::to_string;
```

Comment: _"It's a proper declaration"_: this is what I missed.

Answer (score 3):

This using declaration

```
using std::to_string;
```

hides the declaration in the global namespace. So the compiler does not see the function ::to_string.

So you have to write

```
using std::to_string;
using ::to_string;
```

And make the unnamed namespace inline.

```
inline namespace
{
    // ...
}
```